# Add value to text box based on the value of another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just started coding and I am trying to make a little webpage that finds the date of birth of a user. So I would like to substract the age from the current year (2017). However I don't know how to do that. Can you help me?
Html code:

```html
<body>
  <h1 id="title"> Date of birth finder
    <h1>
      <h2 id="age"> Insert your age here: </h2>
      <div>
        <form>
          <input type="number" name="quantity" min="0" max="2016">
        </form>
      </div>
      <button id="bSubmit">Submit</button>
      <div class="user-answer">
        <form>
          <input type="text" name="year">
        </form>
      </div>
</body>

<script>
  var age = document.getElementById("quantity").value
  $("bSubmit").on(click, function {

  });
</script>
```

Comment: If you want to show the name in the year textbox, then just replace the `console.log()` in @programmer5000 's answer to `$('input[name=year]').val()`

Comment: @Yatin actually, my answer does that now.

Comment: @programmer5000 Wonderful. I was thinking I should have just asked you to edit instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution also updates based on the current year:

```
$("#bSubmit").on("click", function (){
    $("[name='year']").val((new Date()).getFullYear() - $("[name='quantity']").val());
});
```

If you don't want that:

```
$("#bSubmit").on("click", function (){
    $("[name='year']").val(2017 - $("[name='quantity']").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons why your script isn't working as expected:

1. You need to add the brackets at the end of your function.
2. You need to use an `id` attribute in order to target with `getElementById`, not just a `name` attribute. That would be written in HTML as `<input id="quantity" name="quantity">`
3. The `click` in jQuery's `on()` needs to be written in quotation marks.
4. You need to refer to the submit button `bSubmit` with a hashtag at the start (which denotes that it's an ID that you're referencing).
5. You need to define `age` **within** the function, or else the value won't get updated when you change it.

Here's an updated, working script :)

```js
$("#bSubmit").on('click', function() {
  var age = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
  console.log(age);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id="age"> Insert your age here: </h2>
<div>
  <form>
    <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="0" max="2016">
  </form>
</div>
<button id="bSubmit">Submit</button>
```

If instead you'd like to replace the `user-answer`, simply subtract the input from the current date instead of logging to the console:

```js
$("#bSubmit").on('click', function() {
  var age = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
  $("[name='year']").val((new Date()).getFullYear() - age);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id="age"> Insert your age here: </h2>
<div>
  <form>
    <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="0" max="2016">
  </form>
</div>
<button id="bSubmit">Submit</button>
<div class="user-answer">
  <form>
    Current year minus input: <input type="text" name="year">
  </form>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#bSubmit").on("click", function (){
    $("[name='year']").val(new Date.getFullYear() - $("[name='quantity']").val());
});
```

- refining programmer5000 example

Comment: @programmer5000 you deserve +1 for that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this code, it may give you some luck as to what your looking for.

```
$("#bSubmit").on("click", function () 
{
    age = document.getElementById("quantity");
    year_of_birth = 2017 - age;
});
```